# Ffmpeg - Create a HLS video with different versions and creating a master playlist

Tags: ffmpeg

I have this ffmpeg command in order to create an HLS video with four versions with different quality features, but I don't manage it creates the .m3u8 playlist. I have added at the end of the command the control `-master_pl_name`, but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me to create the command I want?

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y \
  -i "MySourceVideo.mp4" \
  -vf scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease \
  -c:a aac \
  -ar 48000 \
  -c:v h264 \
  -profile:v main \
  -crf 20 \
  -sc_threshold 0 \
  -g 48 \
  -keyint_min 48 \
  -hls_time 4 \
  -hls_key_info_file "MyKey.keyinfo" \
  -hls_playlist_type vod \
  -b:v 800k \
  -maxrate 856k \
  -bufsize 1200k \
  -b:a 96k \
  -hls_segment_filename "MyNewVideo_version_360p_%03d.ts" \
  "MyNewVideo_360p.m3u8" \
  \
  -vf  scale=w=842:h=480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease \
  -c:a aac \
  -ar 48000 \
  -c:v h264 \
  -profile:v main \
  -crf 20 \
  -sc_threshold 0 \
  -g 48 -keyint_min 48 \
  -hls_time 4 \
  -hls_key_info_file "MyKey.keyinfo" \
  -hls_playlist_type vod \
  -b:v 1400k \
  -maxrate 1498k \
  -bufsize 2100k \
  -b:a 128k \
  -hls_segment_filename "MyNewVideo_version_480p_%03d.ts" \
  "MyNewVideo_480p.m3u8" \
  \
  -vf scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease \
  -c:a aac \
  -ar 48000 \
  -c:v h264 \
  -profile:v main \
  -crf 20 \
  -sc_threshold 0 \
  -g 48 \
  -keyint_min 48 \
  -hls_time 4 \
  -hls_key_info_file "MyKey.keyinfo" \
  -hls_playlist_type vod \
  -b:v 2800k \
  -maxrate 2996k \
  -bufsize 4200k \
  -b:a 128k \
  -hls_segment_filename "MyNewVideo_version_720p_%03d.ts" \
  "MyNewVideo_720p.m3u8" \
  \
  -vf scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease \
  -c:a aac \
  -ar 48000 \
  -c:v h264 \
  -profile:v main \
  -crf 20 \
  -sc_threshold 0 \
  -g 48 \
  -keyint_min 48 \
  -hls_time 4 \
  -hls_key_info_file "MyKey.keyinfo" \
  -hls_playlist_type vod \
  -b:v 5000k \
  -maxrate 5350k \
  -bufsize 7500k \
  -b:a 192k \
  -hls_segment_filename "MyNewVideo_version_1080p_%03d.ts" \
  "MyNewVideo_1080p.m3u8" \
  \
  -master_pl_name "MyNewVideo_index.m3u8"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar problem and am equally surprised by the seeming lack of resources about this.

Anyway, I think you'll be able to get a step further if you add a single output file name after `-master_pl_name "MyNewVideo_index.m3u8" output_%v.m3u8`. I would then recommend removing the individual names for the quality streams, otherwise FFmpeg will create them twice.

It's possible you'll then have other issues, as I am, but that should solve your first problem.